# Update UIView to the same height as another UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, constraints

Story Board :

[image: storyboard]

I need to update the UIView with the black background to the same height as the UIView with the yellow background.

i write this but it's not work:

```
let heightOfTopBar = self.topBarUserNavigationView.bounds.height
heightProfilView.constant = heightOfTopBar
```

Can you help me to solve this little problem ? Thank you

Comment: Seems easy enough to do in storyboard, why need to use code? Try to put your code in `viewDidLayoutSubview` but replace `-=` with `=`

Comment: call self.view. layoutIfNeeded() method

Comment: When do you need to update this height? After an action, or should be always with same height?

Comment: @Tj3n I remove the minus but the height is not equal again at the other UIview

Comment: @karthikeyan what did you mean?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio Yes after an action is for that i can't use storyboard

Comment: @Daphyduck You have to call `layoutIfNeeded()` to update your view, like karthikeyan said

Comment: Agree with everybody, if the change happens after an action, then `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` has already been called, so it's needed to call `layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: Your are changing NSLayoutConstraint class property called constant so u should call self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: When I test this in the function viewDidLayoutSubviews() this show that : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/27/4/1530788231-capture-d-ecran-2018-07-05-a-12-55-40.png so the UIView to update was again so big

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio Yes but the size increase and dont equal to the topBarUiView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add from storyboard a `Equal Height` constraint and make it disabled by default.

[image]

Then, after the action is done, enable that constraint by doing:

```
heightConstraint.isActive = true
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Can I animate with this method ?

Comment: put the `view.layoutIfNeeded()` inside your `UIView.animate` closure

Comment: Ok, it's works, and I know why! It's because the first Constraint was a multiplier 0.33 of his superview. The second one where I install after your suggestion is in Constant not mulitplier! Thanks you

Comment: Be sure the constraint IBOutlet is not weak :D

Comment: Yes I turn isActive to false in the other height Constraint, thanks